# Prove by mathematical induction that $31\mid5^{n+1}+6^{2n-1},\;$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: induction, divisibility, proof-explanation

The proof of the statement $\mathcal{S}(n)=31\mid5^{n+1}+6^{2n-1}$ is going to be conducted by mathematical induction in terms of $n\in\mathbb{N}.$

**1. Base clause**

Show that $\mathcal{S}(1)$ holds.

$$\begin{align}\mathcal{S}(1)&=31\mid5^{1+1}+6^{2\cdot1-1}\\&=31\mid5^2+6\\&=31\mid25+6\\&=31\mid31\;\checkmark\end{align}$$

**2. Induction hypothesis**

Assume that $\mathcal{S}(n)$ holds for any fixed but arbitrary $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

**3. Induction step**

Show that $\mathcal{S}(n+1)$ holds.
$$ \begin{align} \mathcal{S}(n+1) & = 31\mid5^{(n+1)+1}+6^{2(n+1)-1} \\ & = 31\mid5^{n+2}+6^{2n+1} \\ & = 31\mid5^{n+1}\cdot5+6^{2n-1}\cdot6^2 \end{align} $$

At this point I don't know how to proceed. I really do have the feeling of missing something terribly obvious.

I tried to recreate the terms of the sum in the original statement $\mathcal{S}(n)$ with the goal of figuring out how to apply the induction hypothesis.

At this point I am also aware that $$\mathcal{S}(n)\Leftrightarrow \exists\varphi\in\mathbb{N}:31\varphi=5^{n+1}+6^{2n-1}$$
and therefore 
$$\mathcal{S}(n+1)\Leftrightarrow \exists\varphi\in\mathbb{N}:31\varphi=5^{n+1}\cdot5+6^{2n-1}\cdot6^2$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First, show that this is true for $n=1$:**

$6^{2-1}+5^{1+1}=31$

**Second, assume that this is true for $n$:**

$6^{2n-1}+5^{n+1}=31k$

**Third, prove that this is true for $n+1$:**

$6^{2n+1}+5^{n+2}=$

$36\cdot6^{2n-1}+5\cdot5^{n+1}=$

$36\cdot6^{2n-1}+(36-31)\cdot5^{n+1}=$

$36\cdot6^{2n-1}+36\cdot5^{n+1}-31\cdot5^{n+1}=$

$36\cdot(\color\red{6^{2n-1}+5^{n+1}})-31\cdot5^{n+1}=$

$36\cdot\color\red{31k}-31\cdot5^{n+1}=$

$31\cdot(36k-5^{n+1})$

---

Please note that the assumption is used only in the part marked red.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that $36-31=5$! The step containing the distribution $(36-31) \cdot 5^{n+1}$ was crucial for establishing the inductive step. Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

HINT: $$5^{n+2}+6^{2n+1}=5\cdot5^{n+1}+\underbrace{36}_{=5+31}\cdot6^{2n-1}=5\cdot(5^{n+1}+6^{2n-1})+31\cdot 6^{2n-1}$$

Comment: Efficient. (+1)

Comment: Thank you @OlivierOloa. I had just seen a similar problem in an exam I was supervising, so I knew what had to be done :P

Answer (score 1):

From the induction hypothesis, $$31\mid (5^{n+1}+6^{2n+1})(5+6^2),$$ or $$31\mid 5^{(n+1)+1}+6^{2(n+1)+1}+5\cdot 6^{2n+1}+6^2\cdot 5^{n+1}.$$
So you are left to show
$$31\mid 5\cdot 6^{2n+1}+6^2\cdot 5^{n+1}.$$
Applying the induction hypothesis again, you have
$$31\mid 6^2\cdot 6^{2n+1}+6^2\cdot 5^{n+1}.$$
So you are left with
$$31\mid (6^2-5)6^{2n+1},$$
which is true.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ The inductive step follows very simply by using $\,\rm{\color{#C00}{CPR}} = $ [Congruence Product Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) to multiply the first two congruences below

$$\begin{align} 
{\rm mod}\,\ 31\!:\qquad\  5\,\ &\equiv\,\  6^{\large 2}\\[0.3em]
5^{\large N+1}&\equiv -6^{\large 2N-1}\ \ \ {\rm i.e.}\ \ P(N)\\
\overset{\rm{\color{#C00}{CPR}}}\Longrightarrow\ \ \ 5^{\large N+2}&\equiv -6^{\large 2N+1}\ \ \ {\rm i.e.}\ \ P(N\!+\!1)
\end{align}$$

**Remark** $\ $ The common inductive proofs using divisibility in other answers essentially do the same thing, i.e. they repeat the *proof* of the Congruence Product Rule in this special case, but expressed in divisibility vs.  congruence language ([e.g. see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1239206/242)).  But unfortunately the product rule is *much* less arithmetically intuitive when expressed as unstructured divisibilities, which greatly complicates the discovery of the inductive step. I explain this at length in other answers, e.g. [see here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1286562/242)