Alternate proof of divisibility of $(a^n - b^n)$ by $(a - b)$
I know that $a-b$ can divide $a^n-b^n$ and I have already seen other proofs in a similar post here. But, I want to know if the following way of proving it is correct or not.
Say we have a G.P. :  $1, \frac{b}{a},\frac{b^2}{a^2},\frac{b^3}{a^3}  , \cdot \cdot \cdot , \frac{b^{n-1}}{a^{n-1}}$
Where, $a$ and $b$ are integers and $a\neq0$
If we add all $n$ terms, we get:
$1+\frac{b}{a}+\frac{b^2}{a^2}+\frac{b^3}{a^3}  + \cdot \cdot \cdot + \frac{b^{n-1}}{a^{n-1}} = \frac{1\cdot\left ( 1 - \left ( \frac{b}{a} \right )^n \right )}{ \left ( 1 - \left ( \frac{b}{a} \right ) \right )}$
This can be rewritten as:$1+\frac{b}{a}+\frac{b^2}{a^2}+\frac{b^3}{a^3}  + \cdot \cdot \cdot + \frac{b^{n-1}}{a^{n-1}} = \frac{a^{1-n}(a^n - b^n)}{(a - b)}$
And then after a few operations it becomes: $ a^{n-1} + a^{n-2}b + \cdot \cdot \cdot + b^{n-1} = \frac{(a^n - b^n)}{(a - b)}$
And because $a, b \in \mathbb{I}$, the L.H.S. is also an integer, which tells us that $a-b$ can divide $a^n-b^n$ regardless if $n$ is odd or even.
Is this way of proving it correct? Because, I find it rather simpler than other methods discussed here: Proof of $a^n+b^n$ divisible by $a+b$ when $n$ is odd

Yes it is completely correct. I also used to prove results like this with this GP method.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification: For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.

I don't find it simpler than https://math.stackexchange.com/a/17796

Not simpler either (than the linked answer).

I am trying to prove it here. I am not using a trick as it is mentioned in the linked answer. I think this can itself serve as a proof of the telescopic series mentioned. It is really reverse engineering of the telescopic series.

This proof involves two hidden inductions (basically, anywhere a "..." appears!); if your students/readers don't know how to do proof by induction, then I'd say it's not great.
The last step is also needlessly complicated. You could instead multiply through and say
$$
(a-b)(a^{n-1} + a^{n-2}b + \cdot \cdot \cdot + b^{n-1}) = (a^n - b^n)
$$
which provides an explicit factorization of $a^n - b^n$, with $a-b$ as one of the factors, showing it's definitely a divisor.

I'm a student(high-school) myself. I know the induction method, but I wanted to find alternatives. As for the last step, I thought it best to state everything explicitly.

I agree. And it's the implicit inductions here that make your proof not really better than alternatives.
